# Dependencias locales usando las herramientas para NodeJS en VS2015

Tags: nodejs, visual-studio-2015

Estoy tratando de compilar un [proyecto](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-node) de nodejs, con VS2015.

El proyecto principal tiene sub proyectos en sub carpetas, es decir que en cada sub-carpeta hay un `package.json` con su propio código y cada uno declara las dependencias a los otros proyectos.

El problema que tengo es que cuando intento correr cualquier ejemplo del proyecto principal, en lugar de utilizar los paquetes de las sub-carpetas, descarga todos los paquetes desde *npm registry*.

Mi pregunta es: ¿Como puedo configurar visual studio para que utilize el código de los sub-proyectos sin descargar los paquetes desde internet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La funcionalidad que estás buscando la proporciona [npm-link](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link) que permite establecer un vínculo simbólico al código fuente de un paquete y así poderlo depurar sin volverse loco. (Este artículo en inglés es muy interesante: [npm link: developing your own npm modules without tears](http://justjs.com/posts/npm-link-developing-your-own-npm-modules-without-tears))

La forma de usarlo en tu caso sería la siguiente:

- En cada uno de los subproyectos ejecutas `npm link`
- En el proyecto principal `npm link subproyecto1` ... `npm link subproyectoN`

He realizado un prueba con **Visual Studio 2015** creando una solución con dos proyectos

```
nodejs-projectdeps
|- nodejs-projectdeps-main
|- nodejs-projectdeps-module1
```

Archivo **package.json** de **nodejs-projectdeps-main**

```
{
  "name": "nodejs-projectdeps-main",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "nodejs-projectdeps-main",
  "main": "app.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "azure": "^0.10.6",
    "nodejs-projectdeps-module1": "0.0.0"
  }
}
```

Archivo **package.json** de **nodejs-projectdeps-module1**

```
{
  "name": "nodejs-projectdeps-module1",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "nodejs-projectdeps-module1",
  "main": "app.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "dockerctl": "0.0.0"
  }
}
```

Después he ejecutado `npm link` en la carteta del proyecto `nodejs-projectdeps-module1` con el siguiente resultado:

```
C:\Users\...\npm\node_modules\nodejs-projectdeps-module1 
  -> C:\src\nodejs-projectdeps\nodejs-projectdeps-module1
```

Luego he ejecutado `npm link nodejs-projectdeps-module1` en la carpeta del proyecto `nodejs-projectdeps-main` y el resultado a sido:

```
C:\src\nodejs-projectdeps-main\node_modules\nodejs-projectdeps-module1 
  -> C:\Users\...\npm\node_modules\nodejs-projectdeps-module1 
    -> C:\src\nodejs-projectdeps\nodejs-projectdeps-module1
```

Así es como queda la solución en **Visual Studio 2015** mostrando las dependencias entre paquetes:

[image: Dependencias Node en VS2015]

**Actualización**: El código fuente de las pruebas que he realizado está publicado en [GitHub](https://github.com/rsciriano/nodejs-projectdeps)

Comment: gracias por la respuesta! luego la probare, se ve muy prometedora.

Comment: Hola @rnrneverdies, por si te es de utilidad, he subido a [GitHub](https://github.com/rsciriano/nodejs-projectdeps) el código con el que he realizado las pruebas. Saludos

Comment: Gracias de nuevo! sera de mucha utilidad. Te avisare luego de probarlo.

Comment: Si quieres puedes dejar una respuesta la misma pregunta que formule en el  SOen: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34909329/nodejs-tools-for-vs2015-with-local-dependencies

Comment: @rnd acabo de responder a tu pregunta en inglés, aunque mi nivel de ingles no es ninguna maravilla. Si ves algo que haya escrito mal no te reparo corregirlo. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Puedes especificar en tu archivo `package.json` la dependencia a un repositorio local en lugar de especificar la versión.

Por ejemplo :

```
{
    ...
    "dependencies": {
        "bar": "file:ruta/a/tu/proyecto"
    }
}
```

Más información en: [package.json - Local Paths](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#local-paths)

Comment: es cierto, pero el problema que tengo con esto es que tendría que mantener el package.json de manera diferente cuando estoy depurando de cuando necesito pushear el repo con los cambios que estoy haciendo. Es bastante tedioso